# Keyboard Shortcuts Across Multiple Mac Keyboards

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I have a weird setup. I use a bluetooth keyboard 90% of the time, but as I don't have my trackpad/mouse, I still use my laptop's keyboard/trackpad 10% of the time. This often results in me having my left hand on my laptop keyboard, and my right hand on my bluetooth keyboard.

This works well when typing, however If I try to do any multi-key (for example shift+f) across both keyboards, the modifier button has no effect.

Is there a way to enable keys be recognized regardless of which keyboard is being used?

Answer (score 3):

Try using Karabiner. This is the app that made this possible for me. But I wish this was embedded into the OS X. Yosemite in particular.